# How to initialize a class member of type fstream&

Tags: c++

I have a class with a member of type fstream&.  This should at some point be attached to a file. When I attempt to write a default constructor, the compiler requires that all class members are initialized.  How do I initialize the fstream member without attaching it to any file yet?  The code and the constructor look something like this:

```
class Catalog {
int n;
std::fstream &ascii_inFile;
}

Catalog::Catalog()
: n(0), 
  ascii_inFile(fstream())
```

I have tried different formats, all of which produce a different error message. For instance, the code above leads to the error

```
error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type 
‘std::fstream& {aka std::basic_fstream<char>&}’ from an rvalue...
```

If, on the other hand, I define the class member without the '&', as

```
std::fstream ascii_inFile;
```

then I get

```
error: field ‘ascii_inFile’ has incomplete type
```

What would be the correct syntax for the initialization? Or alternatively, how do I define the class member so that this works? I do not have c++11.

Comment: Do you want to later attach to an existing file/fstream (you need a pointer to an fstream)? Or do you want to open the file later (you need an fstream)?

Comment: I want to open the file later.

Comment: Then just add an fstream to your class. If the code does not compile, then show an [mcve] so that we can help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's unclear why would you need to store it by reference, but creating it in constructor (not passing it as argument to the constructor).

Having member of type 'std::fstream' (by value, not by reference) is totally correct and **safe**.

Incomplete type error message is caused by not having `#include <fstream>` in your file.

Comment: If fstream include were missing the version with a reference would not work either. And the error message shows that the compiler knows how fstream is declared.

Comment: It probably has it forward declared. Reference size is known, but object size is not until after implementation was provided (included it this case).

Comment: @WernerHenze look up `<iosfwd>`

Comment: @sandyre was right, the header was missing. I still get an error, but it is a different one, and probably unrelated.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is that you want to store a reference to this object, so it has to exist somewhere.
So either you pass on the constructor a reference to a fstream, or you create one (so without the &).
The incomplete type error is because you have to include the proper header as well, which is fstream in this instance.